# error: impossible register constraint in 'asm'

Tags: assembly, compiler-errors

I've run into a problem while compiling a package around, I am not
really a good coder, but I tried fixing it for my self, and it still won't compile.
This is the original bit of code.:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
asm("and $3, %%ecx;"
"shl $3 ,%%ecx;"
"ror %%cl, %0"
: "=r" (value)
: "r" (value), "c" (address));
#else
```

The error is .:

GBAinline.h:139: error: impossible register constraint in 'asm'
( ifdef line is 138 )

And this is how I tried to make it look.:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
asm ("and $3 %%ecx,shl $3 %%ecx,ror %%cl, %0" : "=r" (value): "r" (value), "c" (address));

#else
```

Still, it would not work. It's a gba emulator before anyone ask, VBA, and this is
part of GBAinline.h . This assembler is making me crazy already.

Edit.: The problem above was handled fine, I just was not paying attention to which
compiler I was using.
But now I get this error on this bit of code from a header file, I've put it on pastebin,
to keep things here a bit more tidy... ( Sorry if this is wrong, i can change that later )

This is the header that has the lines that results in errors.:
http://pastebin.com/k3D4cg0d

And this is the C file it refers to.:
http://pastebin.com/Ymg1X5dg

This is giving an error like this.:

```
/var/tmp/cc3zA0lH.s: Assembler messages: /var/tmp/cc3zA0lH.s:69: Error: bad instruction `sw $3,0(r3)',
```

And so on for the rest of those lines.

Comment: The original code looks OK to me. What copiler and platform are you on, e.g. what does `gcc -v` output? You need to deal with x86 assembly and [gcc inline assembly constraints](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constraints.html) to fully understand this code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mackie, my gcc is arm-linux, maybe this is the problem, this code is designed for x86, and I didn't notice it. Also, thanks for the link, I will give it a good look.

Comment: So, I used a x86 compiler, and it worked as a charm! Thanks Mackie, I hadn't paid attention to that.

Comment: You are welcome. If you really want to dive into inline assembly with gcc and x86 [this guide](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-ia/index.html) is a more gentle introduction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That inline assembly is buggy:

1. It uses multi-line strings which effectively concatenate. Without `\n` all appears on one line. Whether your assembler *accepts* statements separated by semicolons makes all the difference there ... some may not.
2. It specifies the same variable as input/output constraint instead of using `"+r"(value)` as ordinarily suggested for this situation.

Without seeing the rest of the code it's not quite clear why the inline assembly statement looks the way it does; Personally, I'd suggest to write it like:

```
asm("ror %%cl, %0" : "+r"(value) : "c"((((uintptr_t)address) & 3) << 3)));
```

because there's little need to do the calculation itself in assembly. The `uintptr_t` (from `<stdint.h>`) cast makes this 32/64bit agnostic as well.

**Edit:**

If you want it for a *different* CPU but x86 / x64, then it obviously needs to be different ... For ARM (*not* Thumb2), it'd be:

```
asm("ROR %0, %0, %1" : "+r"(value) : "r"((((uintptr_t)address) & 3) << 3)));
```

since that's how the rotate instruction there behaves.

**Edit (add reference):**

Regarding the operation performed here as such, [this blog post](http://chsc.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/compiler-optimization/) gives an interesting perspective - namely, that the compiler is quite likely to create the same output for:

```
(a >> shift | a << (8 * sizeof(a) - shift))
```

as for the x86 inline

```
asm("ror %%cl, %0" : "+r"(a) : "c"(shift))
```

Testing this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned int shift = (int)((((uintptr_t)argv) & 3) << 3);
    unsigned int a = argc;
#ifdef USE_ASM
    /*
     * Mark the assembly version with a "nop" instruction in output
     */
    asm("nop\n\t"
        "ror        %%cl, %0" : "+r"(a) : "c"(shift));
    return a;
#else
    return (a >> shift | a << (8 * sizeof(a) - shift));
#endif
}
```

Compile / disassemble it:

```
$ gcc -DUSE_ASM -O8 -c tf.c; objdump -d tf.o

tf.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 :
   0:   83 e6 03                and    $0x3,%esi
   3:   8d 0c f5 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rsi,8),%ecx
   a:   90                      nop
   b:   d3 cf                   ror    %cl,%edi
   d:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
   f:   c3                      retq
$ gcc -O8 -c tf.c; objdump -d tf.o

tf.o:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 :
   0:   83 e6 03                and    $0x3,%esi
   3:   8d 0c f5 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0(,%rsi,8),%ecx
   a:   d3 cf                   ror    %cl,%edi
   c:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
   e:   c3                      retq
```

Ergo, this inline assembly is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks Frank, but I got other files that were supposed to work under arm. Still it's giving me trouble, with these errors        /var/tmp/cc3zA0lH.s: Assembler messages:
    /var/tmp/cc3zA0lH.s:69: Error: bad instruction `sw $3,0(r3)', what I still believe it's a gcc problem, and not the file's, and it's about 25 lines of errors, my guess it's useless to post all since they are all alike. Sorry for my mess here, I am still trying to understand how posting comments work around, but I am trying. Again, thanks for the answers

Comment: @Luis: `sw $3,0(r3)` looks like a MIPS instruction, not x86 or ARM. You need to configure your environment correctly...

Comment: @Mackie: ack, looks like a cross compile setup problem; Luis, how have you set up your cross environment ?

Comment: @Frank, you mean, on the makefile? it's CC=$(CROSS_COMPILE)gcc ( with proper spaces of course ) Sorry for the delay on answer. @ Mackie, I still need to configure the environment? Thanks both of you, I added more informations on my OP.